# existance of solution of Kuramoto model under the effect of inertia.

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Kuramoto model under the effect of inertia is an system of 2nd order ode s.t
$$m\theta''_i+\theta_i'=\omega_i+K/N\sum_{j=1}^N\sin(\theta_j-\theta_i),t>0,i=1,2,...,N$$
$m>0,\omega_i,K>0$ is constant $\theta_i=\theta_i(t)$.
Is there any general theorem which verify this ode with intial value $|\theta_i(0)|,|\theta_i'(0)|<\infty$ has unique solution?
and If there exist the theorem this ode has analytic solution, Please let me know the book which has that theorem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The theorem of Picard-Lindelöf provides local existence and uniqueness.

The equation is composed of smooth terms, so satisfies a local Lipschitz condition.

The equation is sub-linear, thus the solution at most exponentially growing. This ensures that solutions are defined on the whole real line.

The equation is analytical in the sense that all its terms have local expansions as power series. A generalization of the existence theorem then gives that the solution is analytical in the same sense.

If there were a "symbolic quadrature" of the system I'm sure the system would not have gotten the interest it garners.